# Hiding headers of HTML Table

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, styling

I have a `DataFrame` to which I have applied pandas styling and now I am converting it to an HTML table. I don't want the headers of columns to be displayed in my HTML table: how can that be done?
My code to convert a `DataFrame` to a table is:

```
html = df.style.apply(highlight,axis=1) .set_table_attributes('border=0 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataframe table table-hover "').hide_index().render()
```

Comment: pandas has a function called `to_html` and you give as parameter `header=False`. Why are you not using that?

Comment: @jxpython i have a styler object and it is giving me an error " AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_html' ".If possible can you tell me how to properly apply it to the styler object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas style - how to hide the column labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644323/pandas-style-how-to-hide-the-column-labels)