# How to hide the column labels after using .style

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

How do I hide the column labels via pandas style? There is a hide_index() method that removes the index row, unfortunately the hide_column() label removes the entire column (both the header and the data). I just want to hide the headers. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `set_table_styles`

You can set the `style` for the table. [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html)

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(3), ['Look', 'At', 'My', 'Header'])

df.style
```

[image]

```
df.style.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'thead', 'props': [('display', 'none')]}
])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As part of the Styler Enhancements in pandas 1.3.0 [`hide_columns()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html) with no subset will simply hide the columns from display, no longer removing the associated column data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(3), ['Look', 'At', 'My', 'Header'])
df.style.hide_columns()
```

[image: styled table with no header (new hide_columns behaviour)]

---

In pandas 1.4.0 [`hide_columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html) was deprecated ([GH43758](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43758)) in favour of [`hide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) with `axis=...`, but keeps the same behaviour as 1.3.0's [`hide_columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(3), ['Look', 'At', 'My', 'Header'])
df.style.hide(axis='columns')
```

[image: styled table with no header (using hide(axis='columns'))]